# How to get the current value in a for loop?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to write a code for a diminishing formula. I'm stuck in loan balance not getting updated.

Here's a sample photo

[image]

As you can see, it is all the same, it should be updated down.

So far I have this code:

##### blade

```html
@for($i = 0; $i < $terms->weeks; $i++)
    <tr>
        <th>{{ $i + 1 }}</th>
        <th>
            PHP {{ number_format(((double)$total / (double)$terms->weeks) - (double)$loan->amount * ((double)$weekly_interest->interest / 100), 2) }}
        </th>
        <th>
            PHP {{ number_format((double)$loan->amount * ((double)$weekly_interest->interest / 100), 2) }}</th>
        <th>
            PHP {{ number_format(((double)$total / (double)$terms->weeks), 2) }}
        </th>
        <th>
            PHP {{ number_format(((double)$loan->amount) - (((double)$total / (double)$terms->weeks) - (double)$loan->amount * ((double)$weekly_interest->interest / 100)), 2) }}
        </th>
    </tr>
@endfor
```

##### livewire

```php
public function render()
{
    $loan = Loan::whereId($this->loan->id)->first();

    $terms = Terms::whereTerms($loan->terms)->first();

    $interest = (double)$loan->amount * ((double)$loan->interest / 100);
    $total = (double)$loan->amount + (double)$interest;

    $weekly_interest = Interest::whereDuration('weekly')->first();

    return view('livewire.admin.schedule.table-schedule-component', compact('interest', 'total', 'terms', 'weekly_interest'));
}
```

The output should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it should be changing when you are just doing a `for` loop and only using `$i` ? Show us what variable should be changing as I have no idea about the algorithm you are showing us... Also, personal recommendation, do not use `whereId` and then `->first();` as you can use exactly both with `find($this->loan->id);`. One last recommendation, instead of writing raw equations, create a simple class (like a service class or helper class) that will have all this equations inside, so you abstract that and use it everywhere instead of full length equations everywhere... Add a new layer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$loan_balance = 80000;

@for($i = 0; $i < $terms->weeks; $i++) {

......

$balance_week = (((double)$loan->amount) - (((double)$total / (double)$terms->weeks) - (double)$loan->amount * ((double)$weekly_interest->interest / 100)), 2)

$loan_balance = $loan_balance - $balance_week;

<tr>
    <td>
        $loan_balance;
    <td>
</tr>

}
```

Comment: let me try this and get back to you thanks

Comment: how can I do this in blade?